# Spring Batch - Rerun Job with same Job Parameter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

Spring Batch new guy here,so, expect anything.

I have a job that runs successfully to completion with given job parameters `paymentPeriod=1`. Though the requirement expects the job to be able to rerun with same job parameters `paymentPeriod=1` .

I can run job first time with parameter `paymentPeriod=1` with following endpoint from postman

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/jobs")
public class JobController {
    @Autowired
    private JobOperator jobOperator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pay/{paymentPeriod}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void launchPaymentJob(@PathVariable Integer paymentPeriod) throws Exception {
        this.jobOperator.start("paymentJob", String.format("paymentPeriod=%s", paymentPeriod));
    }
}
```

Though when i rerun with same parameters i get `JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException` cannot start a job instance that already exists with name `paymentJob` and `parameters=paymentPeriod=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the concept of Job Instances and Job Executions in Spring Batch, you can't start a COMPLETED job instance again though you can launch same instance of job again & again till its not COMPLETE ( and few more job statuses ).

Job instance uniqueness is achieved by jobId & job parameters.

So if you don't vary your parameters, you can't start a completed job with same instance.

If your REST End Point is restricted to take same value again and again, you need to add a unique parameter within that method and that can very well be - `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()`.

You can use any other unique value though current system time is very convenient.

Convert `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()` to String and append to your parameters with something like , `String.format("paymentPeriod=%s", paymentPeriod+java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis())` instead of what you are currently.

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have question though. When i pass params as concat of `paymentPeriod` and timestamp, on job failure how can i dynamically get the unique job instance value to restart

Comment: By querying your meta data tables with `JobExplorer` You will hardly need that precise id since method looks like something like that , `List<JobInstance> lastInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(
     job.getName(), 0, 1);`

Comment: Documentation is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html)

Comment: How can i pass `paymentPeriod` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` as two parameters using `JobOperator` so that i can easily pick `paymentPeriod` in my `ItemReader` implementation with `@Value("#{jobParameters['paymentPeriod']}") final Integer paymentPeriodId` ?

Comment: (doc)[http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/JobOperator.html#start-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-] says that `parameters - the parameters to launch it with (comma or newline separated name=value pairs)` so you don't concatenate ...simply pass it on as new parameter like , `paymentPeriod=1,time=...`.